# JS Phaser - Why is my sprite not moving

Tags: javascript, debugging, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a game to learn phaser, but my sprite isn't moving. This is the code:

```
Player.prototype.update = function() {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(this, walls);

    this.moving = false;

    if (cursors.up.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.BACKWARD;
        this.moving = true;

    } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.FORWARDS;
        this.moving = true;
    } else if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.LEFT;
        this.moving = true;
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.RIGHT;
        this.moving = true;
    }

    this.requiredFunctions();
};
```

Player inherits from Entity and Entity from GameObject. This is the relevant code from Entity:

```
Entity.prototype.requiredFunctions = function() {
    this.physics();
    this.statusEffects();
    this.move();
    this.animate();

    if(debugMode) {
        this.game.debug.spriteBounds(this);
    }
};
```

I have checked with `console.log(this.body.velocity.x + ", " + this.body.velocity.y)`, and the velocity isn't 0, 0 at the END of update (if I have pressed a key) And also, when I try and put `this.body.velocity.x = 100;` (or any other number) at the end, the player sprite still doesn't move! Is there an obvious solution, please say if you need any more of the code.

Comment: can you provide a simplified fiddle?